# Is netsh available on 64-bit Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, netsh

I'm trying to configure a port with an SSL-certificate on a machine running Windows Server 2008. Configuring the port with netsh on my local computer (Windows 7) works just fine, but I just can't find out how to get netsh for the Windows Server machine.

According to the technical reference, netsh should be available on Windows Server 2008, but I can't find a way to get it. I tried downloading the Windows SDK but it wasn't included.

Does netsh even exist for Windows Server 2008? Or httpcfg?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think since Windows XP `netsh` became standard tool in the Windows-family operating systems.

You should be able to use it from the command prompt straight away because it is located at `c:\windows\system32\netsh.exe`. (Plus on 64-bit systems 32-bit version at `c:\Windows\SysWOW64\netsh.exe` so it will work calling from 32-bit applications as well.)

Comment: I sure feel stupid now. It is there, and it is working. Don't know what I was doing wrong before...

Comment: @aspartame, however `httpcfg` is not there because it was [obsoleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364478.aspx) by `netsh` with Windows Vista/2008

Answer (score 1):

Typing `netsh` in a command prompt works fine for me on Server 2008. It is definitely included in a standard install.

Comment: Weird. The server I'm using is a virtual machine, I'll try to get a hold of our sysadmin and see if he has any ideas.